# How to share the value from one component to another component using angular

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, i had tried to send the data from promo component to DASHBOARD component these two are siblings components, i had used the getter and setter methods to save and render the value to other component.

In promo.component.ts :

```
this.EnvironmentDefault= this.promoAnalyserForm.value.selectedenv; 
this.GetService.SETenv(this.EnvironmentDefault); // I had set the environment value
```

In service file:

```
public SETenv(MYEnv:string){
  this.MYEnv = MYEnv;
}

public getENv() { 
  return this.MYEnv; // MYEnv type is string
}
```

dashboard.component.ts :

```
this.DefEnv = this.GetService.getENv(); //Get method
```

If i use the getENv in promo component (i.e, the first component)then it is returning the value but in using it on Dashboard component it is showing me as undefined.

Can any one help me on this, is there any other way to do this .

Comment: you have a lot of options here: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction